Need advice about my CrystalDiscInfo result
I recently checked my D: disk on CrystalDiskInfo, and it found this result:

I am having issues of blue screen of death errors caused by memory management. I am sure something on the D: disk is causing this. And I have troubles about installing big installations, like DayZ or Windows Update, but without any problem on my C: disk.
One time, the HP Omen PC said Hard disk error. Please run the hard disk test in System Diagnostics. and I did. I can't remember much which one, but I run disk check on system diagnostic of HP, and it found an error on my disk 1, which is ST1000LM049. Do I need to change it, or can it be fixed by software?


I am having issues of blue screen errors caused by memory management. I am sure something on D: disc causing this.

Given the HDD situation, it's probably caused by the OS failing to read parts of the pagefile back from the disk into memory.

Do I need to change it or can it be fixed by a software?

You need to change it.
It can't be fixed by software anymore, because "Reallocated sectors" were the software fix – disk firmware fix, more precisely, where the HDD automatically remapped some sectors corresponding to a damaged location to another spare physical location. Sometimes the system fixes bad sectors via software in this way without you even noticing.
By the time you reach >1000 such sectors, though, the disk is already suspicious, and if you somehow reached >50k reallocated sectors, that most likely means it's literally dying.

There's a bit of a meme amongst some SU old timers about the disk of impending doom - a drive I used to own that would fail smart tests, come back to life after a full wipe, and did so more than once.
This drive's doom is impending.
You really want to back up and replace this drive as soon as possible. A reallocated sector count means that its having physical errors, and is doing its best to work around it. There's a distinct chance this drive will fail in the near future.
On the short term

backup
run a short smart test, and if it fails, the drive's probably dying.
if it passes the short smart test, run the long one.

In theory, a wipe and reformat ensures bad blocks are reallocated - but this hides the underlying problem, not solves it, and you could possibly use it for files you don't care about. At some point though, the damage is going to be too bad to work around, and you want your data off before not after this.
